# STM32H7 performance

Tags: performance, stm32

I would appreciate a brief explanation of how my assembler timing loop on a NUCLEO-H723ZG board indicates that it is being executed in a single cpu clock cycle. The two instructions used, a SUBS and a BNE, consume three clock cycles when the loop is branching so there is some magic afoot! I am using the GPIO BSRR to toggle a LED and need to use a timing loop count of 275M to achieve an approximate one flash per second.

Comment: Can you add your code? The Cortex M7 can dual issue arithmetic and load store instructions which makes timing based on instruction counts tricky. It sounds like you'd be better off using a timer to handle your timing.

Comment: The timing code comprises just the two instructions mentioned. Because they are executed a quarter of a billion times the GPIO code is irrelevant from a timing point of view. The exercise is to demonstrate the performance of the processor not one of strict timing accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Cortex M0, M3 and M4 the cycle counts are included in the technical reference manual ([eg Cortex M4](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Instruction-set-summary/Cortex-M4-instructions?lang=en)).  For the M7 they are [not published](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0489/b/programmers-model/instruction-set-summary), but it sounds like you have measured the answer for yourself so do not need it to be in the manual in this case.

If your code is correct, then the processor is able do those two instructions in a single cycle.

This is not surprising.  For example the M4 can carry out a 16-bit data processing instruction and `it` instruction in a single cycle.

You can disable this if you require deterministic (but worse) performance.  See the DISFOLD bit in the Auxiliary Control Register.

Comment: Thanks Tom V. The data speaks for itself! A simple counter loop’s two instructions, taking 3 clocks on an M4, takes a single clock on an M7! I have been brought into the world of twin ALUs!

Comment: Well the M7 should be 3 something better than the M4!  If the question is solved would you mind accepting the answer with the tick mark on the left?  Thanks.